# calculate sine and cosine functions with precision

Tags: java

How to calculate sine and cosine functions with some precision in java?

Because standard `sin` and `cos` does not allow to do that.

Comment: How much precision do you need?  What datatype do you want to return the result in?

Comment: … and what makes you think that the standard `sin` and `cos` aren't precise enough? Hopefully this will make you laugh, but we have had the question “`sin(3.14)` is `0.0015927`. Shouldn't it be zero?” on this site.

Comment: I removed the part of the question where you ask for a library, because we try to avoid such questions here. The question itself is legitimate I think.

Comment: @PascalCuoq It makes my mouth laugh, but my eyes cry.

Comment: I have a task to calculate it with some input(user writes it himself) precision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansion of *sin* and *cos* to calculate them to arbitrary precision:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Evaluating the Taylor series with precision is actually quite hard - so I don't think this is a "solution".

Comment: @Floris Sure, but it reduces the problem to basic operations with an arbitrary-precision library that doesn't provide cos or sin, such as java.math.BigDecimal --  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html.

Comment: As long as the answer does not suggest what precision to start with for a given target precision of the result and a given argument, this is not a real answer.

Comment: @user1432980 You can accumulate the values, i.e. have one variable for the `x` power and another for the factorial denominator. On each iteration, you can multiply appropriately, as opposed to finding `pow(x,n)` and `n!` anew on each iteration.

Comment: @user1432980 The more terms you calculate, the more precise the calculation will be. However, it is difficult to actually quantify the precision. Do you need to do this?

Comment: If you do decide to use this expression, do two things: 1) reduce the parameter `x` to the domain [0 pi/2]; 2) compute the terms separately then combine them (add them) starting with the smallest number. It will improve your accuracy.

Answer (score 13):

The Taylor expansion (or more properly, the Maclauren expansion, which is Taylor about x=0) is not a good way to do this calculation. Most computers use the [CORDIC algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordic) - it has the advantage of converging to arbitrary precision in a finite number of iterations, and requiring only very simple math.

The other thing to keep in mind: you really want to start with an accurate way to reduce the parameter `x` to be in the range [0 pi/2], taking care of the sign of the answer using simple logic. When x gets large, the Maclauren (Taylor) expansion will oscillate for a very long time.

This means, among other things, that you need to know the value of `pi` to at least the number of digits of your desired answer, plus however many digits more you need to reduce `x` (because if x = 1000000, you need another 6 digits of pi just to have the answer with sufficient accuracy in the reduced domain).

Ultimately you will have fewer digits of accuracy in your result than the precision of your calculation - according to the source above, with 64 bit doubles your number increases in accuracy for 48 iterations of the algorithm (about 1 in 2^48 precision). Since the significand for a double is 53 bits, that is actually not too bad (within 5 bits of the precision used in the calculation).

A java implementation of the algorithm can be found [in this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19437035/1967396). It would be interesting to see how it compares with a Taylor expansion...

**EDIT** [this paper](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~marks/cgi-bin/pubs/fastSSE2.pdf) compares the convergence of CORDIS and Taylor's expansion, and concludes that Taylor is faster when you are working in the reduced domain (so after bringing x into [0 pi/2]). It also has a rather neat reformulation that gets around a lot of the rounding errors - making it more accurate than a brute force evaluation of the terms.

Comment: Sadly the "This paper" link is broken. Could you please add a citation?

Comment: After some more search [arXiv:1410.7176](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7176.pdf) is a good reference on fast implementations of sine and cosine in the intermediate precision range (<4096 bits).