# Python: Calculate sine/cosine with a precision of up to 1 million digits

Tags: python, trigonometry

Question is pretty self-explanatory. I've seen a couple of examples for pi but not for trigo functions. Maybe one could use a Taylor series [as done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797951/calculate-sine-and-cosine-functions-with-precision) but I'm not entirely sure how to implement that in python. Especially how to store so many digits.
I should mention: this ideally would run on vanilla python i.e. no numpy etc.

Thanks!

Edit: as said, I know the question has been asked before but it's in java and I was looking for a python implementation :)

Edit 2: wow I wasn't aware people here can be so self-absorbed. I did try several approaches but none would work. I thought this a place you can ask for advice, guess I was wrong

last edit: For anyone who might find this useful: many angles can be calculated as a multiple of sqrt(2), sqrt(3) and Phi (1.61803..) Since those numbers are widely available with a precision up to 10mio digits, it's useful to have them in a file and read them in your program directly

Comment: you should check the `decimal` module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate sine and cosine functions with precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797951/calculate-sine-and-cosine-functions-with-precision)

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at implementing the algorithm you linked to?

Comment: Two first duckduckgo hits for "python arbitrary precision" are http://mpmath.org/ and http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/ . It looks like you did not even bother to search the web before asking.

Comment: Scott Hunter and euxodos: maybe read before posting, I said it should run on vanilla python, no extra modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) is the way:

```
from mpmath import mp
precision = 1000000
mp.dps = precision
mp.cos(0.1)
```

---

If unable to install mpmath or any other module you could try polynomial approximation as suggested.

[image]

where *Rn* is the **Lagrange Remainder**

[image]

Note that *Rn* grows fast as soon as *x* moves away from the center *x<sub>0</sub>*, so be careful using **Maclaurin series** (Taylor series centered in 0) when trying to calculate *sin(x)* or *cos(x)* of **arbitrary** *x*.

[image: Bad idea: infinity does not exist in computers]

[image: Bad idea: infinity does not exist in computers]

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
import math
from decimal import *


def sin_taylor(x, decimals):
    p = 0
    getcontext().prec = decimals
    for n in range(decimals):
        p += Decimal(((-1)**n)*(x**(2*n+1)))/(Decimal(math.factorial(2*n+1)))
    return p


def cos_taylor(x, decimals):
    p = 0
    getcontext().prec = decimals
    for n in range(decimals):
        p += Decimal(((-1)**n)*(x**(2*n)))/(Decimal(math.factorial(2*n)))
    return p

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ang = 0.1
    decimals = 1000000
    print('sin:', sin_taylor(ang, decimals))
    print('cos:', cos_taylor(ang, decimals))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
x = .5
def sin(x):
    sum = 0
    for a in range(0,50): #this number (50) to be changed for more accurate results
        sum+=(math.pow(-1,a))/(math.factorial(2*a+1))*(math.pow(x,2*a+1))
    return sum
    
ans = sin(x)
print('{0:.15f}'.format(ans)) #change the 15 for more decimal places
```

Here is an example of implementing the Taylor series using python as you suggested above. Changing to cos wouldn't be too hard after that.

**EDIT:**

Added in the formatting of the last line in order to actual print out more decimal places.

Comment: OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float when trying your code with range 0 to 500 :(