# Creating a custom sine function

Tags: c, factorial, trigonometry, taylor-series

I tried to create a custom `sine` function using `c` and the [Taylor Series](http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf) for calculating `sin` with 10 terms in the series, but I'm getting the wrong results when I try to find the `sine(x)` where `x > 6`.

It works well for `-5 < x < 5`, but anything out of that range isn't producing the correct results.

I expect `sin(10)` to return something close to `-0.5440`, but get `1418.0269775391`

I've put everything in a single file so it's easier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double factorial(double n);
double power(double n, double pow);
double sine(double n);

// This is supposed to all go in a .c file and reference the .h stuff above
// This is the actual implementation of the functions declared above
double factorial(double n) {
    // 0! = 1 so just return it
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Recursively call factorial with n-1 until n == 0
    return n * (factorial(n - 1)); 
}


double power(double n, double power) {
    double result = n;
    // Loop as many times as the power and just multiply itself power amount of times
    for(int i = 1; i < power; i++) {
        result = n * result;
    }
    return result;
}

double sine(double n) {
    double result = n;
    double coefficent = 3; // Increment this by 2 each loop
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Change 10 to go out to more/less terms
        double pow = power(n, coefficent);
        double frac = factorial(coefficent);
        printf("Loop %d:\n%2.3f ^ %2.3f = %2.3f\n", i, n, coefficent, pow);
        printf("%2.3f! = %2.3f\n", coefficent, frac);

        // Switch between adding/subtracting
        if(i % 2 == 0) { // If the index of the loop is divided by 2, the index is even, so subtract
            result = result - (pow/frac); // x - ((x^3)/(3!)) - ((x^5)/(5!))...
        } else {
            result = result + (pow/frac); // x - ((x^3)/(3!)) + ((x^5)/(5!))...
        }
        coefficent = coefficent + 2;
        printf("Result = %2.3f\n\n", result);
    }
    return result;
}

// main starting point. This is suppossed to #include "functions.c" which contain the above functions in it
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    double number = atof(argv[1]); // argv[1] = "6"
    double sineResult = sine(number);
    printf("%1.10f", sineResult);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: If you haven't tried it before, now is a good time to [learn how to debug our programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: And *why* do you do `double number = atof("5")`? Why not simply `double number = 5.0`? Or just call `sine(5.0)`? Or since the function takes an `int` argument, `int number = 5;` or `sine(5)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have debugged it, and it's doing what is expected for `sin(1)` through `sin(5)`. I have no other reason as to why it wouldn't work for any other `sin(x)`. I'm also using `atof("5")` in place of `atof(argv[1])`.

Comment: You're using `int` in many places. Eventually one of those is going to overflow. For example `power(10, 10)` won't return the right answer (because the right answer is 10 billion, which doesn't fit in a 32-bit `int`).

Comment: The edit to `float` doesn't help much. At least use `double` everywhere.

Comment: Ok, so now the question is: what is the value of the 10th term. Note that as `x` gets bigger, the numerator of each term grows faster, which means you need more terms for the denominator to catch up. The best solution is to subtract or add 2π as needed until `x` is between -π and π. That way, you only need enough terms to get accurate results for small values of `x`.

Comment: In `sine(n)`, first use `n = fmod(n, 2*pi);` or equivalent..

Comment: you have one `int` left in `power`, Change that to `double` and `sine(6)` will come up as `-0.279` wich comes close enough to the more precise result `-0.27941549819892587281`.

Comment: Quality range reduction for radians is a more difficult problem than calculating `sine()`.   See [https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf)

Comment: @chux I'm trying to do it without using any other resources.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi So my logic was correct, it just had to do with preciseness in using `double` over `int` and `float`?

Comment: @JustinJmnz Use `n = fmod(n, 2*pi);` first to see if that solves the issues.  Then find reduction ideas "without using any other resources".

Comment: 'sine(x)'?  What does 'x' represent?  degrees, radians, aiming quadrants, what?

Comment: @user3629249 In the context of a Taylor series, it's radians.

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char** argv) {`  Neither of the parameters are used, so either the first two lines int he body of `main()` should be: `(void)argc;` and `(void)argv;`  or the signature should be: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: the function: `double power(double n, double power) {`  the working value is a `int` ((int result = n;)) and the returned value is an `int`  ((return result;)) This does not agree with the logic of the function nor with the signature of the function, which states that the returned type will be a `double`

Comment: regarding: `double coefficent = 3;`  this variable is being declared as `double`, so why pass it a `int`?  Suggest: `double coefficent = 3.0;`  Similarly for `coefficent = coefficent + 2;`  Suggest: `coefficent = coefficent + 2.0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already said in [Python: Calculate sine/cosine with a precision of up to 1 million digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169675/python-calculate-sine-cosine-with-a-precision-of-up-to-1-million-digits)

> The real Taylor expansion centered in *x<sub>0</sub>* is:
>
> [image]
>
> where *R<sub>n</sub>* is the **Lagrange Remainder**
>
> [image]
>
> Note that *R<sub>n</sub>* grows fast as soon as *x* moves away from the center
>   *x<sub>0</sub>*.
>
> Since you are implementing the **Maclaurin series** (Taylor series
>   centered in 0) and not the general **Taylor series**, your function
>   will give really wrong results when trying to calculate *sin(x)* for
>   big values of *x*.

So before the `for` loop in your `sine()` function you must reduce the domain to at least **[-pi, pi]**... better if you reduce it to **[0, pi]** and take advantage of sine's parity.

To fix your code you'll need [`fmod()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/) from `math.h`, so you can do:

```
#include <math.h>

// Your code

double sine (double n) {
    // Define PI
    const double my_pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    // Sine's period is 2*PI
    n = fmod(n, 2 * my_pi);
    // Any negative angle can be brought back
    // to it's equivalent positive angle
    if (n < 0) {
        n = 2 * my_pi - n;
    }
    // Sine is an odd function...
    // let's take advantage of it.
    char sign = 1;
    if (n > my_pi) {
        n -= my_pi;
        sign = -1;
    }
    // Now n is in range [0, PI].

    // The rest of your function is fine

    return sign * result;
}
```

Now if you really hate `math.h` module, you can implement your own `fmod()` like this,

```
double fmod(double a, double b)
{
    double frac = a / b;
    int floor = frac > 0 ? (int)frac : (int)(frac - 0.9999999999999999);
    return (a - b * floor);
}
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPLbtswELzrK7YpDEi25OgRp3Fkuz/QU65NW0g06RCQSYOSWxSFv91dknpQtpHoQnK0szvkzpJoR8j5/JkLUh23FFZ1s@Vy/rbxRlDFS415W3ksKwqsII1UvKj8FhAB/PMAP858Aes1xB2gP0WboxKQ5AY5eQ4mYAr@kE5ABEkQ5OCd@mIH@YeqvlAILtxVaTFF62PVwBqELcWk8rlogCOU5LisLA23s9lYYUdEPfZwQ2z3Y9DG9nLbSSt6aWXgjWQxVRDMXcA9lDatFsUqKRXC5u8GYvgKWmxgzs9275tDBPF8efEFuavMLzCoRO0maeBKrLmgV20iUtRNJ2//99dBv1A2Tx6SxTJ9XGSLp@WXZZZmTw@Pto7QQvVlsQEp1jGcVgNngI1bjXuuCX0gihPue5K3QqGwnTB9cZJs2sSjRNHaonmPtdSod5RZ3nNCCxNJGeOECv0ruzZJbE2SxFcOGVyHYdaS@BRDviC/DG27Ppj7ZvBBYW3m332T8gCT7fOrmKTzjMFPsOvarq/iLgQewqhmqIXcyGUYn0ZUl6SFOSwcWQ4TbNbl2I4Go91E4GPN@4sUJ6BVTT@gzm5T@92oN85hBun1FV@65O0VzSVtocB1mjskxjVTd4p12/cFF6b/hdqR0FhzOtWH3/otXPOI476kemKLRjJfR3xPfgQjf@lh66WZybOkNqpvUDJPYoaKh/iLeY71DJ/P5yT@Dw)

Answer (score 1):

after making the corrections, as listed in my comments to the question, the proposed code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double factorial(double n);
double power(double n, double pow);
double sine(double n);

// This is supposed to all go in a .c file and reference the .h stuff above
// This is the actual implementation of the functions declared above
double factorial(double n) {
    // 0! = 1 so just return it
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    // Recursively call factorial with n-1 until n == 0
    return n * (factorial(n - 1));
}


double power(double n, double power) {
    double result = n;
    // Loop as many times as the power and just multiply itself power amount of times
    for(int i = 1; i < power; i++) {
        result = n * result;
    }
    return result;
}

double sine(double n) {
    double result = n;
    double coefficent = 3.0; // Increment this by 2 each loop

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Change 10 to go out to more/less terms
        double pow = power(n, coefficent);
        double frac = factorial(coefficent);
        printf("Loop %d:\n%2.3f ^ %2.3f = %2.3f\n", i, n, coefficent, pow);
        printf("%2.3f! = %2.3f\n", coefficent, frac);

        // Switch between adding/subtracting
        if(i % 2 == 0) { // If the index of the loop is divided by 2, the index is even, so subtract
            result = result - (pow/frac); // x - ((x^3)/(3!)) - ((x^5)/(5!))...
        } else {
            result = result + (pow/frac); // x - ((x^3)/(3!)) + ((x^5)/(5!))...
        }
        coefficent = coefficent + 2;
        printf("Result = %2.3f\n\n", result);
    }
    return result;
}


// main starting point. This is suppossed to #include "functions.c" which contain the above functions in it
int main( void )
{
    double number = atof("6");
    double sineResult = sine(number);
    printf("%1.10f", sineResult);
    return (0);
}
```

and the resulting output looks like:

```
Loop 0:
6.000 ^ 3.000 = 216.000
3.000! = 6.000
Result = -30.000

Loop 1:
6.000 ^ 5.000 = 7776.000
5.000! = 120.000
Result = 34.800

Loop 2:
6.000 ^ 7.000 = 279936.000
7.000! = 5040.000
Result = -20.743

Loop 3:
6.000 ^ 9.000 = 10077696.000
9.000! = 362880.000
Result = 7.029

Loop 4:
6.000 ^ 11.000 = 362797056.000
11.000! = 39916800.000
Result = -2.060

Loop 5:
6.000 ^ 13.000 = 13060694016.000
13.000! = 6227020800.000
Result = 0.037

Loop 6:
6.000 ^ 15.000 = 470184984576.000
15.000! = 1307674368000.000
Result = -0.322

Loop 7:
6.000 ^ 17.000 = 16926659444736.000
17.000! = 355687428096000.000
Result = -0.275

Loop 8:
6.000 ^ 19.000 = 609359740010496.000
19.000! = 121645100408832000.000
Result = -0.280

Loop 9:
6.000 ^ 21.000 = 21936950640377856.000
21.000! = 51090942171709440000.000
Result = -0.279

-0.2793866930
```

Answer (score 0):

Taylor expansion has an error that depends on the argument scope as well as the order of the Taylor expansion. I believe that you have overreached the boundaries of the argument. See here for more examples: www.dotancohen.com/eng/taylor-sine.php